# MainScreen not pop after calling popScreen()

Tags: blackberry

I try to pop the main screen using
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getScreen());

But after executing this line main screen not poped and my application hanged.
And I received the following message from console.

```
FocusHistory: Focus lost; App AppName; Component net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField
```

Comment: try this UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());

Comment: possible duplicate of [UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684697/uiapplication-getuiapplication-popscreen-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

try to use

> UiApplication.getUiApplication.popScreen((UiApplication.getUiApplication().getA‌​ctiveScreen())

Answer (score 0):

UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);

```
        Or
```

UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());