# UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen() not working

Tags: blackberry

I got this message: when i pop the Screen

```
FocusHistory: Focus lost; App AppName; Component net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField
```

Comment: show me the code which you have used

Comment: by "not working" what do you mean?  What do you expect will happen?  What is actually happening? What have you tried to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen()  is deprecated .... try using

UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(Screen _screen);

Answer (score 0):

1)   UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);

2) 
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());